# Getting file returned using FileContentResult and writing it to a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asmx

Right now, I have a web service (.asmx) that calls a mvc 4 controller action returning a PDF file via:

```
return  File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf", "Report.pdf");
```

And I'm getting the result in the web service like this:

```
 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
 var status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
 var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
 string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

What I want is to write the file returned into the file system. Something like this:

```
byte[] responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseFromServer);

var file = File.Create("C://Report.pdf");
file.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
```

But the file written has all the pages in blank.

What am I missing here?

---

The solution to this was to get the bytes **directly** from the response stream.

Like this:

```
var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream() ;

byte[] responseBytes;


using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
     dataStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
     responseBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

     return responseBytes;
}
```

Comment: PDF is a binary format and you're reading the data back as a string?

Comment: I'm just using the StreamReader to easily read the bytes

Comment: "Easily read the bytes".  But they get turned in to a **string**.

Comment: But I can do something like this byte[] responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseFromServer); to get the bytes

Comment: These are bytes in a binary file format, you *don't want them encoded*.

Comment: Yes, perhaps that is what is messing with the file information. Thanks Moo-Juice, I'll check that.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, rather than editing your question

Comment: I tried that first, but as I have reputation under 10, I need to wait 8 hours to answer my own question. But don't worry, I will.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the `WebResponse` object for this. Use the `WebClient` instead. It is great for downloading binary data over `http`. All you need to do is replace your webservice´s code with:

```
var serverUrl = "http://localhost:60176/Demo/PdfFile"; //... replace with the request url

var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
var responseBytes = client.DownloadData(serverUrl);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\Report.pdf", responseBytes);
```

Good luck!

Comment: The problem is I need to send POST data to the request